# ReferenceError: Kg is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, referenceerror

I am using Next.JS for my project. All of a sudden I am getting this error.
"ReferenceError: Kg is not defined", after debugging it i found the file which is causing this issue.
file name is VM3284, file content is

```
(function Rn(SJ, Vf) {
    //somecode
  let GB = UL ? UL ? "tCtx" : po : po
      , IF = UL ? Kg + GB : wX
      , IQ = UL ? 4 : VW
      , C = nK ? 0 : po;
  //somecode
}
```

I don't know if is this a third-party library code or something.

I tried googling it but didn't find the answer. please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error
"KG is not defined"
it started after adding a free video with url.
Finally I found out that the error made by an add-Block chrome extension. After i deleted the extension the error stopped.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).